# Fancybox content disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

When I try to click a field the content goes away. I only want the x button to close the popup not the overlay or content. I also notice that when I double click on the #contactus and #contactus2 the popup goes away but not the overlay.

Please click on "View the lines" to see the popup.

Here is the fire code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("#contactus").fancybox({
        'hideOnOverlayClick':false,
        'hideOnContentClick':false
});

    $("#contactus2").fancybox({
       'hideOnOverlayClick':false,
       'hideOnContentClick': false
});

    $("a#inline").fancybox({
        'hideOnContentClick': false
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to clarify what I said below:

you have a call to fancybox on the link with id=inline (you have two links with the same id, you should probably be using a class instead). the links with the id=inline are opening up their targets, which are div#contactus and div#contactus2. you are also calling fancybox on div#contactus and div#contactus2, which is causing those divs to open a fancybox.

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u3NyM/).

it looks like this line:

```
    $("#contactus2").fancybox({
   'hideOnOverlayClick':false,
   'hideOnContentClick': false

});
```

is causing a click on the div inside the fancybox to open ANOTHER fancybox inside. try removing that and clicking Houston to see if it works.

Comment: I did before I will change it watch

Comment: there are 2 popups houston and dallas

Comment: do you have any javascript being fired when you click in a field?

Comment: there are 2 of them dallas --> #contactus and houston --> #contactus2

Comment: @Jes, my point is that by putting a fancybox call on $('#contactus2') is making a fancybox pop up *when you click the div itself*  you dont' need that or the call on #contactus.

Comment: still don;t get it can you just give me the correct script and html to correct it because it's not making any sense

Comment: @Jes `can you just give me the correct script and html to correct it` sounds like "can you do my work so I can charge my client?" ;)

Comment: no it is not I was asking for the correct fire script  and a different way to do the html she is talking about that is it.

Comment: honestly if you read and understood my answer, and looked at the fiddle I provided I have no idea why you would still be unable to make this work. you may also want to read and understand the instructions on how to use fancybox while you are at it.